# PHP - Sorting directory alphabetically on drop down list

Tags: php, sorting, directory

How would I sort the directory to display the drop down list alphabetically?

```
<select name=country>
<?php
$handle=opendir("images/flags");
while (false!==($file = readdir($handle))) { 
  if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
    $country = substr($file,0,strpos($file,'.'));
    echo "<option value=\"".$file."\"><center>".$country."</center></option>\n";
  } 
}
closedir($handle);
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )
```

> By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order. If
>   the optional sorting_order is set to SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING, then the
>   sort order is alphabetical in descending order. If it is set to
>   SCANDIR_SORT_NONE then the result is unsorted.

More Reading on [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

**Another Solution:**

```
<?php
$dir = "images/flags";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

sort($files);

print_r($files);

rsort($files);

print_r($files);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use :

```
$ao = new ArrayObject(iterator_to_array(new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__ ."/test", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)));
$ao->natsort(); //sort directory 
foreach ( $ao as $file ) {
    echo $file->getPathname() . PHP_EOL; 
}
```